# devExpress Xtragrid: how to get/set rowheight located at index n

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using devExpress gridview and I want to get/set row height for any row whose index I have. For example, I have a gridview with 50 records, I want to increase height of any row where I click. I can get rowindex where I click but unable to set row height.
I am using devExpress 13 for windows form application.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this task, add the following helper class to your project:

```
   public class GridRowZoomHelper
{
    public GridView GridView { get; set; }

    public int ZoomedRowHeight { get; set; }
    private int _ZoomedRowHandle;
    public int ZoomedRowHandle
    {
        get
        {
            return _ZoomedRowHandle;
        }
        set
        {

            if (_ZoomedRowHandle == value)
                return;
            var prevValue = _ZoomedRowHandle;
            _ZoomedRowHandle = value;
            OnZoomedRowHandleChanged(prevValue, value);
        }
    }
    public GridRowZoomHelper(GridView gridView)
    {
        GridView = gridView;
        ZoomedRowHeight = 60;
        ZoomedRowHandle = GridControl.InvalidRowHandle;
        GridView.RowClick += GridView_RowClick;
        GridView.CalcRowHeight += GridView_CalcRowHeight;
        GridView.ShownEditor += GridView_ShownEditor;
    }

    void GridView_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZoomedRowHandle = GridView.FocusedRowHandle;
    }

    void GridView_CalcRowHeight(object sender, RowHeightEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowHandle == ZoomedRowHandle)
            e.RowHeight = ZoomedRowHeight;
    }

    void GridView_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ZoomedRowHandle = e.RowHandle;
    }

    private void OnZoomedRowHandleChanged(int prevValue, int value)
    {
        GridView.RefreshData();
    }
}
```

Then, register it in the following manner:

```
  new GridRowZoomHelper(gridView1).ZoomedRowHeight = 60;
```

As a result, clicking a row will automatically increase its height:

[image: Auto row zoom]